# Cannot Access Console

Tags: plugins, php

http://bigpicturepartnering.com
I can log into the site. When I try to access the WP console I get the following error:
PHP Fatal error: Call to undefined function is_site_admin() in D:\websites\bigpicturepartnering\wp-content\plugins\wordpress-related-posts\related-posts.php on line 81

How can I get into the console to disable the plugin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the FTP client of your choice, go to `wp-content\plugins\`, and delete (or move) the `wordpress-related-posts` directory.

By the way: what version of WordPress are you using? And is this a local install or a live site?

Comment: Looks like WP 3.1.3 and he linked to a live site in the question.

Comment: I'm... not always able to follow links. ;)

Comment: Thanks Chip - I thought so but was afraid to try w/o confirmation. Delete at the server-a man after my own heart! I'm doing a favor, so I don't know yet what the setup is. I saw the D:\websites\ directory too and wondered.